# c++11 random doubles using uniform_real_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random

So I am trying to get uniform random `double`s using the following for my random number generation:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 randEng(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rg(std::numeric_limits<double>::min(), std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
```

and then of course calling `rg(randEng)`

However if I use the numeric limits of the double like this I am not getting a random sample that are from -DOUBLE to +DOUBLE. Instead I am getting numbers that are in the order of maginute e+306 or e+307 or e+308. Is there something I am doing wrong here that will not allow me to get the range that I am looking for?

If I put in something else like -10, 10 to the uniform distribution I do get valid numbers in that range. Is there something going on here for doubles that I am missing?

Comment: double min gives me `2.2250738585072014e-308`, is this what you expecting? or you want negative double max

Comment: Ah yes i did want negative "max" of double

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153548/minimum-double-value-in-c-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::min()
```

is the double value with smallest absolute value.
if you want the smallest negative (highest abs), you can use

```
-std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
```

Technically, there may also be

```
numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity
-numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
```

But that does not seem to be what you want

Comment: Don't forget [`std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem; `std::numeric_limited<double>::min()` will return something like `2.2250738585072014e-308`, which is a positive value. It's in scientific notation; the `e-308` means you want to move the decimal place to the left about 308 times.